# 'You are running version ' + process.version + ' of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

[image]I have following versions installed on my system:
node : v8.12.0
npm  : 6.4.1

Now, when I try to run ng --version or any other command starting with ng, I am getting following error :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
try {
  process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');
} catch(_) {
  // If an error happened above, use the most basic title.
  process.title = 'ng';
}

// Some older versions of Node do not support let or const.
var version = process.version.substr(1).split('.');
if (Number(version[0]) < 8 || (Number(version[0]) === 8 && Number(version[1]) < 9)) {
  process.stderr.write(
    'You are running version ' + process.version + ' of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6.\n' +
    'The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater.\n\n' +
    'Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.\n'
  );

  process.exit(3);
}

require('../lib/init');
```

when I type ng I get following message (see image)
Any help is much appreciated !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying to fix this issue. Finally I found out that the path variable that I was setting was not correct .
then I gave it correct path where ng is downloaded inside Appdata-> Roaming and it started working.

Hope It might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to open the project with powershell, it looks this:
[image]

but I tried to open it with the Command Prompt and it works!
You can make the change here:
[image]

Your version of node.js should be higher than v12.14 or v14.15.
You will see that with `node --version`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Open the cmd as much as admin then, download your project from git

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY

npm i

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@12.2.8

ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use angular v6 with node < v8.9. You have to update your node version to 8.9 or higher or downgrade the angular version to v5.

the latest version of angular supported with node version less than 8.9 is angular/cli@1.7.4 as starting from the commit of 6.0.0-beta.3 [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/29338bca) angular/cli requires node 8.9 or higher.

To downgrade to angular v5 do the following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4
```