# New Angular application creation

Tags: node.js, angular

after entering the command
[ng new app_name]
in vs code's terminal it creates a file with the text given below

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */

/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable import/no-unassigned-import */
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
try {
  process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');
} catch (_) {
  // If an error happened above, use the most basic title.
  process.title = 'ng';
}
```

this file is bit long so i have pasted some lines from upper half.

I am unable to figure out why i am not able to create a new app.

Comment: npx nx @angular/cli new app_name

Comment: @pixelbits thankyou for the response
do i have to use this command for creating new app

Comment: You may want to open the CLI - command line standalone instead of run the command inside VSC or any code editors. This thread also suggests the node version is not compatible with cli's version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757248/you-are-running-version-process-version-of-node-js-which-is-not-suppor

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as your `cli` was not correctly installed or broken. You can try the follow:

```
ng version
```

It would be show some information about version of Angular CLI, Node and so on.

If it not working, install the cli again:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

About `npx` you can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-the-differences-between-npm-and-npx/).

> NPX: The npx stands for Node Package Execute and it comes with the npm, when you installed npm above 5.2.0 version then automatically npx will installed. It is an npm package runner that can execute any package that you want from the npm registry without even installing that package. The npx is useful during a single time use package. If you have installed npm below 5.2.0 then npx is not installed in your system. You can check npx is installed or not by running the following command:

So it's nothing wrong to use `npx` if it works you.

Comment: while checking for ng version it automatically minimise my command prompt and doesn't show the version 
i have tried uninstalling and re-installing cli multiple times still getting this file as error.